# Regex split on combination of capital letter and period for abbreviated first names

Tags: python, regex

This is my string:

```
'C. AndersonN. ChubbD. ForemanT. GurleyM. IngramA. JonesJ. Richard'
```

I'd like to use regex to split on the capital letter + period to generate a list like this:

```
['C. Anderson', 'N. Chubb', 'D. Foreman', 'T. Gurley', 'M. Ingram', 'A. Jones', 'J. Richard']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With split you could use [`\B(?=[A-Z]\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/WiL5JJ/1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of splitting, you can use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) for a simpler regex expression:

```
import re
s = 'C. AndersonN. ChubbD. ForemanT. GurleyM. IngramA. JonesJ. Richard'
new_s = re.findall('[A-Z]\.\s[A-Z][a-z]+', s)
```

Output:

```
['C. Anderson', 'N. Chubb', 'D. Foreman', 'T. Gurley', 'M. Ingram', 'A. Jones', 'J. Richard']
```